# How to implement componentWillMount in a Walmart electrode react app?

Tags: reactjs, walmart-electrode

I'm trying to get started with Walamart's electrode react app framework and not sure how to add behavior for when the application mounts.  I want to setup app authentication using auth0.lock and wish to implement initializing it in the app `componentDidMount` function.

http://www.electrode.io/docs/whats_inside.html

How can I add it to the app.jsx file?  Is that the right place to do so?  Is window.webappStart expecting a react component to be returned?

```
//
// This is the client side entry point for the React app.
//

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { routes } from './routes';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import './styles/base.css';

//
// Add the client app start up code to a function as window.webappStart.
// The webapp's full HTML will check and call it once the js-content
// DOM is created.
//

window.webappStart = () => {
  const initialState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>{routes}</Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('.js-content')
  );
};
```